# css inheritance in iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm aware that an iframe can't inherit the css styles of the "main" webpage, but if so I am confused. I have a main page whose background is plain black, with white text. The iframe doesn't have a background colour specified and yet it is black, the same as the main page. However, other css properties in the main page have to be defined separately for the iframe if I want them to be used. Why is this?

Comment: Is the source URL of the IFrame end with `wmode=transparent`?

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems all iframes without a specified background inherit. Strange since no other CSS properties inherit.

Comment: No, theres no such decoration on the iframe. All I specify in the iframe tag is the width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not set the background of an HTML document (by setting it on its `html` element or its `body` element), the browser default will be used, and it can be expected to be the initial value, `transparent`.

This means that for a page embedded in another page with the `iframe` element, you can expect the background of the embedding page to shine through.

Comment: Thank you, this answers its perfectly. I suppose it would have to have some default value, I'm a bit suprised that it it taken from the parent/main window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Developer Tools** to figure out where the black background is coming from. (It's built into the browser.)

If you are using IE or Chrome, you can just **press F12 on your keyboard** and then use the element selector (top left) to select the `IFrame`. On the left you will then find all the `CSS` styles that are applied on that `IFrame`.

This will give you an insight on what's happening and also give you a new priceless tool to debug in the browser.

Note: If you use firefox, you will need to install firebug.

---

This can also come useful.

Precedence rules in CSS (1 is most Precedent):

1. User defined style
2. Embedded or inline style sheet
3. Internal style sheet
4. External style sheet
5. Browser default style

---

This may be Firefox specific. See [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154957) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=346398).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting firebug. It looks like an excellent utility.

I'm still looking but I can't see any inherited css properties in the iframe. It lists the iframe specific css properties though.

Comment: I've just looked on Chrome and it says that the background colour is inherited from the main page's body, but the text color style is crossed out. Odd.

Comment: That means something else has precedence. I edited my answer with the precedence rules.

Comment: I have the css defined inside the <head></head> tags for both the main and iframe pages, if that helps. I can't see whats wrong but I am not an expert!

Comment: Can you post what the CSS is?

Comment: In the main page, its this:

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    } 
    </style>

Comment: In the iframe its: <style type="text/css">
body {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.testfont
{
    font-size:25px;
}
</style>

Comment: I think this is Firefox related. Try a different browser. Saw these two links https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154957 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=346398

Comment: I just looked at it in chrome and I get the same thing. The iframe inherits the main body colour.

Comment: I've just looked on the in-built browser on my Android phone and I get the same thing too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55350/discussion-between-simcha-khabinsky-and-user3713442).

Comment: Sorry, I saw your post too late (I went to bed as it was 2am in the UK). Yes, let us chat. I'm still perplexed. It does the same thing on Safari on an iPad.